# Can't load loadSavedPreferences() from aonther class

Tags: android, class, sharedpreferences

I have a class A extends Activity, where I have the following method:

```
public void loadSavedPreferences() {
    System.out.println("Test");
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        System.out.println("Test2");
        boolean checkBoxValueb = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Valueb", false);
        boolean checkBoxValuew = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Valuew", false);
        boolean checkBoxValuen = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Valuen", false);

        if (checkBoxValueb) {
            View background = findViewById(R.id.background);
            background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgb);
            setTheme(R.style.BlackTheme);
        } else if{....
```

}

Now I want to use this method from class B (extends Activity too)

```
public A test = new A()
```

later:

```
test.loadSavedPreferences()
```

it started the method, cause I see "Test" in my LogCat. but I fail loading the SharedPreferences. It doesn't matter what context I use (getapplicationcontext(), this, A.class)

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate Activity class (in another activity, but generally anywhere).

Instead, instantiate `SharedPreferences` in Activity B the same way you did it in Activity A by calling:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Then, calling

```
boolean checkBoxValueb = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Valueb", false);
boolean checkBoxValuew = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Valuew", false);
boolean checkBoxValuen = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Valuen", false);
```

will give you the same values.

Basically, copy the same code (whole method) to the other Activity.

---

By the way, `A.class` is not a `Context`, it is a type of `Class`.